# Significance of the Servlet code

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

I am learning Servlets.
In web.xml of an application, I found the following Servlet code.

Can somebody please explain me the significance of the code

```
<servlet id="Servlet_1060120206078">
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param id="InitParam_1060120206077">
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param id="InitParam_1060120206076">
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param id="InitParam_1069371544495">
        <param-name>detail</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param id="InitParam_1069371544496">
        <param-name>validate</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Thanks
Nirmalya

Comment: Check document: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1039287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just defining a servlet (in this case a FrontController for Struts) that is used to handle requests. Later on in the file I'm sure you'll also find a servlet mapping that maps this servlet to http requests.

The `<init-param>` elements are key/value pairs that the servlet can read on startup. Struts uses these for configuration.

All the InitParam_XXX stuff is un-necessary, my guess is that it was machine generated by some editor.

Check this out for more details:

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-struts.html

Comment: Thanks.. I was just confused at the numbers mentioned at InitParam_xxx.
One more thing. In the code below am I specifying the path and the name of the config file for struts.
<init-param id="InitParam_1060120206077">
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

If I define that value as struts.xml then I should have a config file named as struts.xml ??